# Исправить проблему с зависимостями классов

Tags: php

Структура папок:

src

--Element.php

--elements

----fire

------fire.php

----water

------water.php

----earth

------earth.php

----air

------air.php

В каждом файле air.php, water.php etc есть класс и в нем магические функции __construct и __call у которых код ВЕЗДЕ одинаковый. Хочу этот повторяющийся код вынести в файл Element.php и обращаться к функциям классов air.php, water.php etc через файл Element.php
Как это сделать? Контейнер зависимостей?

Comment: Самое время почитать про [наследование](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

Comment: Наследование не подходит. Так как использовать любой файл через Element.php надо динамически

Comment: Что в вашем понимании значит "динамически"? Приведите пример как и что надо использовать

Comment: Здесь просто две задачи, одна это "Хочу этот повторяющийся код вынести в файл", и вторая "желаю к отдельным элементам обращаться через главный". И если по отдельности они и несут хоть какой-то смысл, то вместе, конечно, получается очень смешная ерунда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился. Надо использовать DI, никаких наследований.